# Creating data access to possibly changing schemas

Tags: c#, .net, database, orm, ado.net

The product I'm working on will need to support different database types. At first, it needs to support **SQL Server** and **Oracle**, but in the future it may need to support **IBM DB2** and **Postgre SQL**.

And the product will need to be working for different customers who might have slightly different schemas. For example a column name on one client with *SQL Server* might be `_ID` and on another client with *Oracle* it could be `I_ID`.

The general schema will be the same except the column names. They all could potentially be mapped to the same object. **But**, there may be some extra columns that are specific to each customer. These do not need to be mapped to an object though. They can be retrieved in a *Master-Detail* scenario using a simpler way.

I wanted use an ORM as we will need to support different types of database providers. But as far as I can understand, ORMs are not good with creating a mapping on runtime.

**To support these requests (summary):**

1. Column names may be different for each customer, but they are pretty much the same columns except names.
2. Database provider may be different for each customer.
3. There may be extra columns for each customer.
4. **Edit:** Program should be able to support a new database by changing the configuration during runtime.

What is a good way to create a data access for such specifications? Is there a way to do it with ORMs? Or do I need to write code specific to each database to support this scenario? Do I have any other option that would make it easier than using ADO.NET directly?

**Edit:** I think I wrote my question a bit too broad, and didn't explain it clearly, sorry about that. The problem is I won't be creating the databases. They will be created already, and the program should be able to work with a new database by configuring the program during runtime. I have no control over the databases.

The other thing is, of course it is possible to do it by creating SQL statements in the program, but that is really cumbersome. All these providers have slightly different rules and different SQL implementations, so it is a lot of work. I was wondering if I could use something like an ORM to make it easier for me.

**Edit 2:** I am totally aware that this is a stupid way to do things, and it shows bad design decisions. But I have spent so many hours trying to convince my company to not do it this way. They don't want to change their way of thinking because an intern tells them so. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> **Column names may be different for each customer, but they pretty much the same columns except names.**

Because of this requirement alone you're going to have to build your SQL statement dynamically, on your own, but it's really pretty straight forward. I would recommend building a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name SYSNAME NOT NULL
)
```

to store all of the tables in the database. Then build one like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DataTableField (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DataTableID INT NOT NULL,
    Name SYSNAME NOT NULL
)
```

to store the base names for the fields. You'll just have to pick a schema and call it the *baseline*. That's what goes in those two tables. Then you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)
```

to store all the unique customers you have using the product, and then finally a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerDataTableField (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
    DataTableFieldID INT NOT NULL,
    Name SYSNAME,
    IsCustom BIT
)
```

to store the different field names for each customer. We'll discuss the `IsCustom` in a minute.

Now you can leverage these tables to build your SQL statements dynamically. In C#, you might cache all this data up front when the application first loads and then use those data structures to build the SQL statements. But get started on that and if you have specific questions about that then create a new question, add the code you already have, and let us know where you're having trouble.

> **Database provider may be different for each customer.**

Here you're going to need to use something like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) because it works with POCO classes (like what you'll be building) and it also simply extends the `IDbConnection` interface so it doesn't matter what concrete class you use (e.g. `SqlConnection` or `OracleConnection`), it works the same.

> **There may be extra columns for each customer.**

This is actually quite straight forward. Leverage the `IsCustom` field in the `CustomerDataTableField` table to add those fields to your dynamically built SQL statements. That solves the database side. Now, to solve the class side, I'm going to recommend you leverage `partial` classes. So consider a class like this:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

and that represents the *baseline* schema. Now, everything maps into those fields except those marked `IsCustom`, so we need to do something about those. Well, let's build an extension to this class:

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

and so now when you build a `new MyTable()` it will always have these additional fields. **But,** you don't want that for every customer do you? Well, that's why we use `partial` classes, you define these `partial` classes in external assemblies that only get installed for the right customer. Now you have a bunch of small, customer specific extensions to the system, and they are easily developed, installed, and maintained.

Comment: I think I wrote my question a bit too broad, and didn't explain it clearly, sorry about that. The problem is I won't be creating the databases. They will be created already, and the program should be able to work with a new database by configuring it during runtime. The other thing is, of course it is possible to do it by creating SQL statements in the program, but that is really cumbersome. All these providers have slightly different rules and different SQL implementations, so it is a lot of work. I was wondering if I could use something like an ORM to make it easier for me.

Comment: @hattenn, let me tell you this, you're headed down a rabbit hole you don't want to get into. I've been down that rabbit hole. I wrote a piece of software one time that could connect to any database provider and could be configured at runtime without being shut down. You know what it ended being moved to -what I just described. Configure the systems, build the partial classes, compile the code, and install it. Trust me, you don't want to go down the other rabbit hole.

Comment: Believe me, I am aware of that. I have spent around 4-5 hours yesterday trying to convince my company to not do it this way. But they don't understand, and I will have to support this somehow.

Comment: @hattenn, it's just as flexible this way. You have to find a way to convince them of that. The configuration has to be done by hand anyway right? So while it's being configured the users can't reload the configuration because it could be in a partial state. You do the configuration, build it, and deploy it. It's that simple. Build in a basic auto-update feature and you're golden. Same flexibility -but no problems, that's the difference. See, when an application is configurable at runtime you can actually get it into a state where it won't even load (I know this).

Comment: I have spent a long time creating a solution that works pretty well with Entity Framework to show them and they are not happy with it. I'll try to convince them otherwise still, but I'm not sure they will be convinced, so till that time I somehow need to look for other ways.

Comment: @hattenn, well the best of luck to you my friend. A little advice, if you go down the rabbit hole you'll have to store your data in `dynamic` classes or in data structures like a `Dictionary`. We leveraged the latter. It's pretty fast. The configuration will still be necessary (i.e. what I provided for configuration tables) but **all configuration will need to be cached.** We also leveraged the `Dictionary` for this. Our UX was even fully configurable and dynamic, so I know how dark this hole is, so again I wish you best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, it's appreciated.